# DOS batch file to read contents of a file and rename the file based on a condition

Tags: file, batch-file, dos

I need to create a batch file that reads a file with one line and then renames the same file based on the contents.
The file will have one number and the condition to rename the file is this:

If content of file > 100 then rename new.txt to old.txt
else rename new.txt to new1.txt

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you really need to do this in DOS? I have severe doubts about that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p line=<new.txt
if %line% GTR 100 (
  ren "new.txt" "old.txt"
)else (
  ren "new.txt "new1.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

***Note:*** I'm assuming you don't need to do this in DOS but instead with a Windows batch file. Otherwise this gets far uglier than it needs to be.

If the file only has a single line the easiest way of reading the contents of that file is to use `set /p` and redirect the file's contents:

```
set /p Content=<new.txt
```

You then have the first line of the file in `%Content%` and can compare based on that:

```
if %Content% GTR 100 (ren new.txt old.txt) else (ren new.txt new1.txt)
```

(`GTR` is the “greater than” operator; using `>` would obviously a bad idea.)

Comment: Thank you for the help with this.
I used the solutions to create a windows batch file that looks like this:

@echo off
:BEGIN

pushd D:\Data_Files\FTP\MISC

set /p Content=<Count.txt 

if %Content% GTR 100 (ren Count.txt OK.txt) else (ren Count.txt Abort.txt) 

:END


But every time I run it, I get a "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. More? " error...Ideas?